# how to convert a String sentence to arraylist in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have this function to convert string sentence to list words. I created this function in Java and converted to Kotlin using default Kotlin conversion in Android Studio, but I believe there can be many ways to shorten this code in Awesome Kotlin. I will be good if you can share your piece of code and help me(and all) to improve our knowledge in Kotlin.

```
private fun stringToWords(mnemonic: String): List<String> {
    val words = ArrayList<String>()
    for (word in mnemonic.trim { it <= ' ' }.split(" ".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()) {
        if (word.isNotEmpty()) {
            words.add(word)
        }
    }
    return words
}
```

Comment: Can you share the original java function as well?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/januprasad/8e4f2a8f520e0f8839bbe8e23496ac04

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would go for the following:

```
fun stringToWords(s : String) = s.trim().splitToSequence(' ')
    .filter { it.isNotEmpty() } // or: .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
    .toList()
```

Note that you probably want to adjust that filter, e.g. to filter out blank entries too... I put that variant in the comment... (if you use that one, you do not require an initial [`trim()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html) though)

If you rather want to work with the [`Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html) you can do so by just omitting the [`.toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/to-list.html) at the end.

And as also Abdul-Aziz-Niazi said: same is also possible via extension function, if you require it more often:

```
fun String.toWords() = trim().splitToSequence(' ').filter { it.isNotEmpty() }.toList()
```

Comment: I Liked it very much because you're doing in Kotlin Way.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier than you think:

```
fun stringToWords(mnemonic: String) = mnemonic.replace("\\s+".toRegex(), " ").trim().split(" ")
```

Remove multiple spaces, trim start and the end, split. 
Like an extention:

```
fun String.toWords() = replace("\\s+".toRegex(), " ").trim().split(" ")
```

After Roland's suggestion:

```
fun String.toWords() = trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this.. Just make a function of return type list.

```
 val s = "This is a sample sentence."

 val words:Array<String>  = s.split("\\s+".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
    for (i in words.indices) {
        // You may want to check for a non-word character before blindly
        // performing a replacement
        // It may also be necessary to adjust the character class
        words[i] = words[i].replace("[^\\w]".toRegex(), "")
    }
```

May this will help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need scopes, the redundant `"".toRegex()` and the last expression.
You can do something like this:

```
private fun stringToWords(mnemonic: String): List<String> {
    val words = ArrayList<String>()
    for (w in mnemonic.trim(' ').split(" ")) {
        if (w.isNotEmpty()) {
            words.add(w)
        }
    }
    return words
}
```

---

Additionally,
If you use this method a lot in this project, you can make it an extension in string class. Paste this method in a separate file(outside a classes or add it in classless .kt file) so it has a global access.
and then you can use it with any string like
`myString.toWords()` anywhere in the project
The method will look like this

```
inline fun String.toWords(): List<String> {
    val words = ArrayList<String>()
    for (w in this.trim(' ').split(" ")) {
        if (w.isNotEmpty()) {
            words.add(w)
        }
    }
    return words
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I heard of Extensions. Great Good Answer.